# Just SQL query in spring data jpa method body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to use native SQL in Spring Boot project.
I tryed this:

```
@Query(value="...", nativeQuery=true)
```

and it don't work for me. For my situation I need to have SQL Query in body of method. What can I do for it?

Comment: No you don't need it in the body. Why doesn't it work when you place it in `value` of the annotation?

Comment: I need to include many conditions to SQL. I want to work with the String and when it will be ready execute it like SQL Query.

Comment: Don't use the criteria API instead. Don't go concatting strings together to create the query.

Comment: My task doesn't have another way solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to execute query in the JPA repository directly. If you need to assemble SQL using various condition EntityManager might be better option.

In the service class autowire EntityManager:

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;
```

Create method which assembles and executes SQL in the same class:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM students ...conditions from input params...";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
List<Object[]> players = query.getResultList();
return players;
```

You don't have to use Object[] as a return type. Generics can be used in this scenario as well.